# Why minus one in "inode->i_ino - 1" of fs/ext2/inode.c?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

The code is:

```
void ext2_read_inode (struct inode * inode)
{
    struct buffer_head * bh;
    struct ext2_inode * raw_inode;
    unsigned long block_group;
    unsigned long group_desc;
    unsigned long desc;
    unsigned long block;
    unsigned long offset;
    struct ext2_group_desc * gdp;

    if (
        ( inode->i_ino != EXT2_ROOT_INO
            && inode->i_ino != EXT2_ACL_IDX_INO
            && inode->i_ino != EXT2_ACL_DATA_INO
            && inode->i_ino < EXT2_FIRST_INO(inode->i_sb)
        ) || inode->i_ino > le32_to_cpu(
                inode->i_sb->u.ext2_sb.s_es->s_inodes_count)
    )
    {
        ext2_error(inode->i_sb, "ext2_read_inode", 
            "bad inode number: %lu", inode->i_ino);
        goto bad_inode;
    }

    block_group = (inode->i_ino - 1) / EXT2_INODES_PER_GROUP(inode->i_sb);

    if (block_group >= inode->i_sb->u.ext2_sb.s_groups_count) {
        ext2_error(inode->i_sb, "ext2_read_inode", "group >= groups count");
        goto bad_inode;
    }

    group_desc = block_group >> EXT2_DESC_PER_BLOCK_BITS(inode->i_sb);
    desc = block_group & (EXT2_DESC_PER_BLOCK(inode->i_sb) - 1);
    bh = inode->i_sb->u.ext2_sb.s_group_desc[group_desc];

    /* ... other code omitted ... */
}
```

Could you explain why there is `-1` here:

```
block_group = (inode->i_ino - 1) / EXT2_INODES_PER_GROUP(inode->i_sb);
```

and here:

```
desc = block_group & (EXT2_DESC_PER_BLOCK(inode->i_sb) - 1);
```

Thank you.

Comment: To make it zero-based?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg what, the correct response doesn't deserve to be in Answer format?

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Because I have no idea if it's correct or not, it was just an educated guess. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the only person for whom that would be more than an "educated guess" would be the developers of the code in question, I'd think. It's still worth being an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To make it zero-based. As you can see, the `i_ino` field in `fs/inode.c` is incremented with `++last_ino`. 
It makes the first `i_ino` equal to 1.

```
/**
 *      new_inode       - obtain an inode
 *      @sb: superblock
 *
 *      Allocates a new inode for given superblock. The default gfp_mask
 *      for allocations related to inode->i_mapping is GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE.
 *      If HIGHMEM pages are unsuitable or it is known that pages allocated
 *      for the page cache are not reclaimable or migratable,
 *      mapping_set_gfp_mask() must be called with suitable flags on the
 *      newly created inode's mapping
 *
 */
struct inode *new_inode(struct super_block *sb)
{
    /*
     * On a 32bit, non LFS stat() call, glibc will generate an EOVERFLOW
     * error if st_ino won't fit in target struct field. Use 32bit counter
     * here to attempt to avoid that.
     */
    static unsigned int last_ino;
    struct inode *inode;

    spin_lock_prefetch(&inode_lock);

    inode = alloc_inode(sb);
    if (inode) {
            spin_lock(&inode_lock);
            __inode_add_to_lists(sb, NULL, inode);
            inode->i_ino = ++last_ino;
            inode->i_state = 0;
            spin_unlock(&inode_lock);
    }
    return inode;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[Dave Poirier - The Second Extended File System: Internal Layout - 3.6. Locating an Inode](http://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/ext2.html#AEN1729) says:

> Knowing that inode 1 is the first inode defined in the inode table,
>   one can use the following formulaes:
>
> `block group = (inode - 1) / s_inodes_per_group`

Here we could say with Joachim Pileborg `- 1` is there to "make it zero-based".

But then, the `- 1` in

```
desc = block_group & (EXT2_DESC_PER_BLOCK(inode->i_sb) - 1);
```

has nothing to do with making something zero-based; it's another way of writing

```
desc = block_group % EXT2_DESC_PER_BLOCK(inode->i_sb);
```

since the number of block group descriptors per block of storage is a power of 2.